# Using pre_get_posts, how to target the REST API, only?

Tags: rest-api

The title says it all: Is it possible to set a condition in `pre_get_posts` that only applies to queries that are targeted at the REST API?

So at https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

So long as the code you're running happens after `parse_request` - which `pre_get_posts` does. (See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request)

Then you will have a nice constant to use: `REST_REQUEST`

Something like

```php
if( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST ) {
    // ...do RESTy things
}
```

will do the trick.

See [/wp-includes/rest-api.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L376)

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work like a charm.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to quite always work as expected: To avoid targeting all queries, you can use $query->is_main_query(), but this doesn't seem to work in combination with this if-then.